# Where do you find higher rated weapons?

Tags: elite-dangerous

All the outfitted parts in Elite: Dangerous have a level and a class, broadly describing their performance.

So you have size 1 (small), 2 (medium) and so on for size ratings and A, B, C etc for class ratings (A being best but super expensive). Size counts more than class, so a 2-anything will be better than a 1 anything, and an A2 will be better than a B2.

Where can I find high class weapons?

I'm currently in an Eagle with 3 small mounts - shouldn't I be able to mount 3 A1 guns eventually (when I can afford them)? The problem is that (even in high tech systems) I haven't seen any size 1 guns better rated than F.

In particular is like to find gimballed size one guns better than a G rating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't**. Currently, the class ranking of weapons doesn't seem to mean anything at all. Your choices of weapons are strictly limited by type, size, and targeting method. There aren't higher class small fixed pulse lasers, for example, there is only one variety of small fixed pulse laser.

What I think is going on here, is the game is ranking weapons based on their overall stats, regardless of power cost, size, or targeting method. For example, a huge plasma accelerator is class A, a medium railgun is class B, and a small fixed pulse laser is class F. There's not a class D small fixed pulse laser, because that's not how that class stat works. You can check out all possible weapons that you can find in the [Elite Shipyard](http://www.edshipyard.com/).

Comment: Odd, but weapons have a class and I'm sure I've seen larger ones with more than one class. Is that not implemented yet or deliberate?

Comment: @keith I'm not certain. My current guess is it ranks weapons relative to all other weapons, but that doesn't necessarily make sense because there are other more important factors to consider. I don't know.